# When running a python program in the terminal, an error is produced not related to the code (windows)

Tags: windows, windows-10, terminal, python, python3

So, I've recently written a python program and wanted to run it in the terminal. However, every time i try to run it, the error "*'x' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.* "
('x' is just a placeholder, I actually have the directory there)

I've tried everything, but it always returns the same error.
What is the problem?
(after the directory I write "*python y.py*" where y = the file name)

Comment: What is 'x'? Is `python.exe` in `%PATH%` environment variable?

Comment: @Biswapriyo so 'x' is actually the first thing typed after the directory ('python'), and I'm not sure about your other question (I'm relatively new to this whole thing).